Google Chart API showing wrong values
For one specific user the numbers in the table is showing wrong. The data is directly coming from the database. No issue in DB or backend. I am attaching the picture of the issue. Along with the code snippet.
       var salesJson = JSON.parse("{{ DSsales | escapejs }}");
       var sales = new google.visualization.DataTable(salesJson, 0.6);
const drawTableB = function (
           aggregateArr,
           groupByArr = [0],
           datatable = sales
           ) {
           const aggregateObjArr = aggregateArr.map((x) => {
               return {
                   column: x,
                   aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg,
                   type: "number",
               };
           });
           console.log(groupByArr)
           const table_B_view_1 = google.visualization.data.group(
               datatable,
               groupByArr,
               aggregateObjArr
           );

           const table_B_options = {
               allowHtml: true,
               title: "Opening by Brand Current Month vs Previous Month",
               alternatingRowStyle: false,
               cssClassNames: {
                   headerCell: "table-header-cells",
                   tableCell: "table-row-cells",
               },
               width: "100%",
               height: "100%",
               sort: "disable",
           };
document.getElementById("table_B_card").classList.remove("d-none");
           var table_B = new google.visualization.Table(
               document.getElementById("table_B")
           );
           table_B.draw(table_B_view_1, table_B_options);
       }



